# How to develop final product in visual studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I use visual studio 2017 for learning C and I wonder how to develop my project to final app without any visual studio project's files. Is there a posibility to make it in VS or do I have to do it manually (like deleting all .sln, .vsxproj etc. files)?

Comment: What is a _final product_ for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're simply looking for it in the wrong place, when you compile your project (as debug or release), it will create an executable for you in the appropriate output folder for the build, with default settings on Windows 10, you can find this in:

```
%Documents%/Visual Studio <version>/Projects/<project>/Debug
```

or:

```
%Documents%/Visual Studio <version>/Projects/<project>/Release
```